# Google app engine Java backend returns "503 Server Error"

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a public dynamic GAE Java backend that works perfectly on the development server but fails to start on the appspot production env. When deployed, the backend shows in the admin console as "Started" but no instances are showing. According to the logs no startup  "/_ah/start" request are ever sent to the backend. I have tried connecting to the backend from a browser and from a front-end instance, always getting the 503 http error.

The backend url is http://vp3engine-alan.vp3editor.appspot.com/engine/session

web.xml snippet:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>EngineSwitch</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vp3engine.GAECabinet.EngineSwitchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EngineSwitch</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/start</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MainSwitch</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>vp3editor.MainSwitchServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MainSwitch</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The backends.xml file:

```
<backends>
    <backend name="vp3engine-alan">
        <options>
            <public>true</public>
            <dynamic>true</dynamic>
            <!-- fail-fast>true</fail-fast -->
        </options>
    </backend>
</backends>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a module instead of a backend? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/converting#Java_Converting_backends_to_Modules

Comment: As modules are not supported yet by the GAE Eclipse plug-in for Java yet, I preferred using Backedns as I do not really require any additional features on top of them.Are Backends deprecated already?